# Could not get the build in androidstudio

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting these errors. I tried npm install. But the errors are still existing.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating script.

  > Command `config` unrecognized. Make sure that you have run `npm install` and that you are inside a react-native project.

Comment: In which directory are you running the `npm install` command?

Comment: I run the command inside the react-native project

Comment: what is the version of `@react-native-community/cli-platform-android` dependency you use in the project. this can be found in package.json under dependencies or devDependencies list

Comment: first of all you have to start your script please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61290145/12386821

Answer (score 0):

Please run following commmand one after another..

```
1.npm start
2.npm run android
```